# How does saving and loading data into a Room database work?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I understand that we can pre-populate a Room database (https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/prepopulate), but I am struggling to get a conceptual model of how, when, and where the data is stored in relation to the Application lifecycle in the first place.

I am presuming that at some point, the database is saved as a file that can then be used to re-populate the Room instance when the app is restarted, but it's unclear to me how this file is saved or when and whether it is a manual or automatic process (or both!).

Is there a concise explanation or diagram available to understand how this process works at a high level?

Answer (score 1):

Data is saved when a transaction occurs if the transaction does in fact update the database. A transaction is by default whenever an SQL statement is executed.

However, statements can be grouped by issuing a `BEGIN TRANSACTION` followed by the statements and then issuing a `COMMIT TRANSACTION` or `END TRANSACTION` (if the execution has been deemed successful) which will then update the file(s).

If the execution has been deemed to be unsuccessful then a `ROLLBACK TRANACTION` can be issued, in which case the changes will be undone and the changes rolled back.

The above is as per SQLite. Room is a wrapper for SQLite and it provides the @Transaction annotation and access via the Room database to `beginTransaction`, `setTransactionSuccessful` and `endTransactio`n methods and additionally the `runInTransaction` method (begin/setSuccessful and end are deprecated). There is also the `inTransaction` method.

You can also use a SupportSQLiteDatabase (obtainable via the RoomDatabase's getOpenHelper method to issue SQL statements directly which could begin and end transactions).

The database is primarily a single file with 1 or 2 support files for logging and rollback. On android by default the file (named according to the name passed to the 3rd parameter of the databaseBuilder).

By default the files will be located in the data/data/<package_name>/databases folder

- <package_name> being App dependant

There will be 1-2 files if the logging mode is JOURNAL the database file and the journal file (database file suffixed with -journal).

- with journal mode updates are written to the database and to the journal allowing the updates to be rolled back.

There will be 1-3 files if the logging mode is WAL (Write Ahead Logging) which is the default used for Room. The database file, the wal file (the database file suffixed with -wal) and the shared memory file (the database file suffixed with -shm).

- with WAL updates are written to the -wal file (and potentially to the -shm which is an index file for the -wal file). The -wal file if not empty is part of the database. Checkpointing applies the -wal file to the database and is typically undertaken when SQLite deems it fit or when the database is closed. A rollback effectively deletes the data from the -wal file.

In short when the file is created, changed or saved is not typically of importance to the App developer as SQLite manages it all.

From a Room point of view (and also non-room) the database file is only created when an attempt is made to access the database for the very first time. For a pre-populated database the file needs to be copied from it's location if the APK (typically the assets folder or subfolder) before the attempt is made to access the database if the database file doesn't already exist. Room provides the RoomBuilder `createFrom????` methods to perform the copy if the database file doesn't exist.

> Is there a concise explanation or diagram available to understand how this process works at a high level?

I don't believe so.

Links that may be of interest :-

- [Transaction](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html)
- [Write Ahead Logging](http://Write-Ahead%20Logging)
- [WAL-mode File Format](https://sqlite.org/walformat.html)
- [Temporary Files Used By SQLite](https://sqlite.org/tempfiles.html)
- [RoomDatabase](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/RoomDatabase)
- [RoomDatabase.Builder](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/RoomDatabase.Builder)